# Query to return percentage of values in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Order_num | Item_Num |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 111 |
| 245 | 111 |
| 367 | 111 |
| 499 | 111 |
| 555 | 333 |

There are 4 orders requesting the same item. Can anyone help me with a SQL query that returns Item_num '111' has been ordered in 80% of the different orders and Item_num '333' has been ordered 20% of different orders.

I want it for different item_num because my table is huge consisting of various item_numbers being ordered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when item_num = '111' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from t;
```

If there can be more than one row per order:

```
select (count(distinct case when item_num = '111' then order_num end) * 1.0 /
        count(distinct order_num)
       )
from t;
```

Alternatively, you can use aggregation to do the calculation for all items:

```
select item_number,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from t
group by item_number;
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I want to display multiple Item numbers and their percentages of being ordered?
Example: I want to display Item number '333' being ordered 20% of the times.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the total count in a variable and use that to calculate the percentage in the sql query.

Below example for MySQL

```
SET @cnt := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Order);

SELECT (c/(@cnt))*100 AS percentage, item FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as c, Item_Num AS item FROM Order GROUP BY Item_Num
)_;
```